# Using a variable to determine which which value in a set to be printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a bit of help on a piece of python code I've been writing for fun, the troublesome piece of code is thus:

```
v = randint(1,7)
if v != 7:
    d = randint(1,5)
    if d == 1:
        print(vdset[v], file=text_file)
```

My aim is to use randint to select a random value from my set, however, when running I get the error that `'set' object does not support indexing`. I suppose then that I need to replace my use of `set` with something else, but I am unsure as to what would work.

Comment: sets are not ordered, so they can't be indexed. You can use a list instead.

Comment: Picking a random element from a sequence is best done using `random.choice()`, by the way. You'd still need a list or tuple however.

Comment: You could `list(vdset)[v]` if you're really wed to `vdset``

Comment: @ShawnMehan: at which point the order is going to greatly depend on the insertion and deletion history. But for random selection that may not be too bad.

Comment: Using list(vdset)[v] or just changing my original set to list gives me a new error; "I/O operation on a closed file."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a set is an unordered collections of unique element. You should have a look at [data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for Python :

You can try :

```
v = randint(1,7)
    if v != 7:
        d = randint(1,5)
        if d == 1:
            print(list(vdset)[v], file=text_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice). This has the same problem where a set doesn't support indexing but you can simply convert the set to a list (which does support indexing).

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> my_set = {1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 4}
>>> choice(my_set)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
>>> choice(list(my_set))
3
```